# Convert column into rows repeating ID

Tags: r, filtering

I have the following dataset

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6)
 
segment <- c(26,28,41,42,26,28,30,31,26,28,30,31,30,31,41,42,30,31,35,40,26,29,41,43)
 
tbl <- tibble(ID, segment)
```

I want to create different vectors with the IDs that have segments = 26 and 28, segments = 41 and 42.

For example in this case, ID 1. 2. 3 have both 26 and 28. And ID 1 and 4 have 41 and 42

Comment: In this case, I get if the segment is 26 or 28. I need it to be 26 and 28 in different lines. For example in this case, ID 1. 2. 3 have both 26 and 28. And ID 1 and 4 have 41 and 42

Comment: It didnt work. The results should be: 26 and 28: 1, 2 and 3. 41 and 42: 1 and 4

Comment: 6 has only 26, doesn't have 28

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
tbl %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   filter(all(c(26, 28) %in% segment), segment %in% c(26, 28)) %>% 
   pull(ID) %>%
   unique
[1] 1 2 3
tbl %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   filter(all(c(41, 42) %in% segment), segment %in% c(41, 42)) %>% 
   pull(ID) %>% 
   unique
[1] 1 4
```